# Difference in "Bundle" and "/Bundle"

Tags: java, resourcebundle

What is the difference between

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle")
```

and this

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle")
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)):

> The `baseName` argument should be a fully qualified class name. However, for compatibility with earlier versions, Sun's Java SE Runtime Environments do not verify this, and so it is possible to access PropertyResourceBundles by specifying a path name (using "/") instead of a fully qualified class name (using ".").

The second form <strike>will load `/Bundle.properties` from the file system (perhaps after appending some modifiers from the default locale).</strike> will probably fail to load anything (tip of the hat to VGR for some experimental computer science). At best it will try load `Bundle.properties` from either the current directory or some file root directory.

Comment: I don't think that's what the documentation is saying.  I believe it is only saying that the slash can be used in place of the period, for compatibility reasons.  Any call to ResourceBundle.getBundle with a name starting with "/" will fail, as far as I can tell (unless of course there is also a ResourceBundle.Control doing its own custom resolution of the name).  I just ran several simple tests which seem to confirm this.

Comment: @VGR - Yeah, I wondered about that. I just tried a similar experiment. Interestingly, on Windows, using the base name `"\\Bundle"` will load from the current directory, while `"/Bundle"` fails to load (even if there's a Bundle.properties in the root directory).